# What is the best way to log and read real-time data simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, logging, real-time-data

I have some  Position(GPS),time and event datas about a project(Data Provider part.This part is implemented in another platform like C# and I am not responsible for this part.) and  I need to process those datas on javascript in real-time.

Currently i am getting data as local .JSON file and i can parse and process data easily.

```
{
  "LOG": [

        {
           "GPS": {"latitude": "20.32123123", "longitude": "40.6323231"}, 
           "Data": "some-data",  
           "time": "18-03-2019 16:53:32.12"
        },
        {
           "GPS": {"latitude": "21.32323231", "longitude": "40.6321323123"}, 
           "Data": "some-data",  
           "time": "18-03-2019 16:54:33.15"
        },
        .
        .
        .


        ]


}
```

But the data provider part needs to firstly parse .JSON data, then append the new data, then re-write to .JSON in order to add new datas on our .JSON format log file.

Is this a proper way of doing this logging-reading works? or is there any other handy methods to write and read real-time log data simultaneously?

Comment: Use a database instead?

Comment: Why can't the data provider send you this fresh data directly?  Can it only communicate through this file?  Also, this file is going to become unmanageable... at least use NDJSON.

Comment: @Brad It can communicate via other ways.I just wanted to know what is the convention about this problem